# Can WebRTC work over an Android USB Ethernet connection?

Tags: webrtc, webrtc-android, android-webrtc

I am trying to use WebRTC on an Android App to stream to a media server running on my workstation using a USB tethering connection.   I see have good signaling, with an offer and an answer that seem to make sense with respect to the IP addresses, but I do not get any UDP streaming traffic.

Is there something in the Android WebRtc library that would omit this `rndis0` interface?  Over Wi-Fi, everything works as intended, but not if the tethered ethernet is the only connection.

Comment: WebRTC works over an rndis interface (I have successfully run it this way on a Raspberry Pi over USB).

Comment: That's an encouraging data point.  I'll have to dig a bit deeper and not give up...  Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar issue.  On wifi connection, all works fine.  But if I change to ethernet the video does not show up.  
Did you find a solution for this yet?

Comment: Nope.  I always use Wi-Fi for now.  I've thought about digging into the source, but haven't had time.  Sorry.